# What is the difference between open( ) and send ( ) methods of XMLHttpRequest object?

Tags: javascript, ajax

`XMLHttpRequest` object:

> `open ( <method>, <url>, <is async>)`
>   `send (<request_data>)`

1. How are these different and why do we need both to implement ajax?
2. Also, can the `<request_data>` be passed through both the methods ?

Comment: Your question has a misconception. The argument to `send()` isn't the URL, it's the data to send in a `POST` request.

Comment: You are not right, `send` takes request data as a parameter: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: your questions are based on that misunderstanding. Now that it is fixed, they no longer make sense. Except the part about needing them both in quesiton 1.

Answer (score 3):

open() does not open the connection; 
it only configures the request, but the network activity only starts with the call of send ()

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP and HTTPS requests of the XMLHttpRequest object must be initialized through the open method. This method must be invoked prior to the actual sending of a request to validate and resolve the request method, URL, and URI user information to be used for the request.
This method does not assure that the URL exists or the user information is correct. This method can accept up to five parameters, but requires only two, to initialize a request.

Answer (score -3):

1.open() method will open specific url ( for open on server) 
2.send() method Sends an HTTP request to the server and receives a response.

Comment: thats why after calling open() send() is called

Comment: What do you mean by "opening" of an url ?

Comment: @Satyendra `open` is how you tell the XHR what URL it should go to. `send()` is how you actually send the request.