# API Binance GET free Balance

Tags: javascript, node.js, binance

I'm new with API and I will appreciate your kind advice.
I would like to recall Binance API "GET /api/v3/account (HMAC SHA256)" to get only the free assets available on my account.

The response with the code I get, it's something like:

```json
{
  "makerCommission": 15,
  "takerCommission": 15,
  "buyerCommission": 0,
  "sellerCommission": 0,
  "canTrade": true,
  "canWithdraw": true,
  "canDeposit": true,
  "updateTime": 123456789,
  "accountType": "SPOT",
  "balances": [
    {
      "asset": "BTC",
      "free": "4723846.89208129",
      "locked": "0.00000000"
    },
    {
      "asset": "LTC",
      "free": "4763368.68006011",
      "locked": "0.00000000"
    }
  ],
    "permissions": [
    "SPOT"
  ]
}
```

I just want the free balance, so I tried using the MAP method, but I'm obtaining this error:

```
Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at Object.<anonymous><C:\Users\etc..
at Module._compile (internal/module/cjs/loader.js1137:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
at Function.executeEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
at internal/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Following my code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var burl = "https://api.binance.com";
var endPoint = "/api/v3/account";
var dataQueryString = "timestamp=" + Date.now();
var keys = {
    "APIkey" :'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA',
    "SECRETkey" : 'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB'
    }
var signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256',keys['SECRETkey']).update(dataQueryString).digest('hex');
var url = burl + endPoint + '?' + dataQueryString + '&signature=' + signature;
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET',url,true);
ourRequest.setRequestHeader('X-MBX-APIKEY', keys['APIkey']);
let arrayCleaned = ourRequest.responseText.balances.map(ele => {
        return {
            "asset" : ele.asset,
            "free" : ele.free
        }
    })
console.log(arrayCleaned);
ourRequest.send();
```

Comment: `responseText` has no property `balances`.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you must be new to AJAX because you are missing 2 important facts

1. AJAX takes time
2. AJAX response is always a string

Consider your snippet

```
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET',url,true);   
//           ^---- doesn't actually send any request https://stackoverflow.com/q/29362977/6160662
ourRequest.setRequestHeader('X-MBX-APIKEY', keys['APIkey']);
let arrayCleaned = ourRequest.responseText.balances.map(ele => {  //Line 4
        return {
            "asset" : ele.asset,
            "free" : ele.free
        }
    })
console.log(arrayCleaned);
ourRequest.send(); //Line 11
```

As you can see you are sending the ajax request on line 11 but you are trying to manipulate the (prospective) data on line 4! hence the error `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at Object`

Next thing is `ourRequest.responseText` is a property that holds the server response in **string** it doesn't have any [map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) property. So you need to convert it into an object by using [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)

So this should work fine

```
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET',url,true);
ourRequest.setRequestHeader('X-MBX-APIKEY', keys['APIkey']);

var arrayCleaned = [];
ourRequest.onload = function () {
    // Convert data string to an object
    var data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText); // string -->to Object

    arrayCleaned = data.balances.map(ele => {
        return {
            "asset" : ele.asset,
            "free" : ele.free
        }
    })
    console.log(arrayCleaned);
};

ourRequest.send();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, very appreciated. Yes I'm new with AJAX, hope to get familiarity with it in few time...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [CCXT](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt) to connect to the binance API?

You can do the following:

```
;(async () => {
    const binance = ccxt.binance ({'apiKey': 'YOURAPIKEY', 'secret': 'YOURSECRET'})
    const balance = await binance.fetchBalance ()
    const free = balance['free']
    console.log (free)
}) ()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you question, but I created my own script to track my portfolio using python.
This may help:

```
    from binance.client import Client

def editar_df_binance(lista):
    df = pd.DataFrame(lista)
    df["free"] = df["free"].astype(float)  #Convertimos las columnas a valores float
    df["locked"] = df["locked"].astype(float)  #Convertimos las columnas a valores float
    filtro1 = df["free"] > 0
    filtro2 = df["locked"] > 0
    df = df[filtro1 | filtro2]
    df["Fecha"] = hoy
    df = df.rename(columns={"asset": "Moneda", "free": "Saldo", "locked": "Bloqueado"}).sort_values(by="Saldo", ascending=False)  #Renombramos y ordenamos
    df["Moneda"] = df["Moneda"].apply(editar_moneda_binance)  #Vamos a corregir el nombre de las monedas de earn que aparecen con "LD"
    df = df[["Fecha", "Moneda", "Saldo", "Bloqueado"]]

    return df
    
def editar_moneda_binance(moneda):
    if moneda.startswith("LD"):
        return moneda.replace("LD", "")
    return moneda
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ###############Balance Binance###################  (Falta la parte de earn)
    api_key = os.environ.get('binance_api')
    api_secret = os.environ.get('binance_secret')
    client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
    diccionario = client.get_account()["balances"]  #Obtener valores de balance
    df_binance = editar_df_binance(diccionario)
```

Then I create an excel file with dataframe.
Please, advice that Binance Earn are not shown.