# Prevent generation of browser history on `POST` to self

Tags: javascript, html, post, browser-history

I have a server that, when `POST` is sent to `/generate`, it generates "stuff" in an HTML page. The page itself uses JavaScript `window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href)` so that the user can reload the page (using `GET`) and see the same data without the browser asking if it should resend `POST` information.

The page also has a "Regenerate" button that sends `POST` back to `/generate` to regenerate new information. Unfortunately this results in a new point in navigation history, so that the user can hit the browser "Back" button to go back to the previous version of the `/generate` page. I don't want this behavior. I want the page to be able to "replace" the current page with the new generated contents without creating a new point in navigation history.

(I am well aware that a more modern approach would be to asynchronously query the server using Ajax and update the page dynamically. I imagine that is what will be done in an upcoming release. I'm asking for a quick workaround for the current release of this product.)

Is there a way that I can have a page send a `POST` so that it doesn't result in a new point in navigation history? The JavaScript on the page can detect if regeneration occurred, but I can't find out how to *remove* the current navigation state, only replace it. Ideally I would like to `POST` without creating a new point in navigation history at all.

I don't see any way this is possible, but I thought I would run it by the community to see if someone knew a trick.

Comment: [Render the page in a proxy through an `<object>` tag maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32854559/1073758)?

Comment: How about using sessionStorage - https://www.javascripttutorial.net/web-apis/javascript-sessionstorage/

Comment: `history.go(-1);`?

Answer (score 0):

Like you have mentioned, it is indeed not possible to prevent generation of browser history. A POST request on the same page will still create a URL, you can only code your way to mask the method or make it look like it's in the same state.

I find the conversations in these two community posts relevant for this matter:

- [history.replaceState() example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832317/history-replacestate-example)
- [What is the difference between open( ) and send ( ) methods of XMLHttpRequest object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29362977/what-is-the-difference-between-open-and-send-methods-of-xmlhttprequest-ob)

Answer (score -1):

## Preface

It's not possible to send a POST request without creating a new point in the navigation history. When you perform a POST request, the browser considers it a new interaction with the server and therefore adds a new entry to the history.

But ***similar behavior can be achieved without adding to the navigation history.***

## Solution

### Approach

1. Attach an event listener to your "Regenerate" button.
2. When the button is clicked, use JavaScript to send a POST request to the server using the Fetch API or an XMLHttpRequest. This allows you to send the data to the server without triggering a page reload.
3. Handle the response from the server and update the page content with the new data.
4. Use the `window.history.replaceState` method to update the URL if necessary.

### Simplified Example

```js
document.getElementById('regenerateButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Perform an asynchronous POST request
    fetch('/generate', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', // Adjust the content type as needed
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ /* Your POST data here */ }),
    })
    .then(response => response.text()) // Assuming the response is text, adjust as needed
    .then(newData => {
        // Update the page content with the new data
        document.getElementById('contentContainer').innerHTML = newData;

        // Optionally, update the URL without adding to the history
        window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
});
```

**NOTE:** I did this hurriedly, so there might be some typo or mistakes.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but please see the part of my question where I say, "I am well aware that a more modern approach would be to asynchronously query the server using Ajax and update the page dynamically." It would appear that you provided a solution to "asynchronously query the server using Ajax and update the page dynamically", exactly what I specified that I was not asking about. Perhaps you didn't notice the sentence because I used an older term, "Ajax", which is what this technique was called when it first gained wide acceptance.

Comment: I appreciate your sarcastic comment (don't know if it was intentional or not), but please see the part of my answer where I say "It's not possible to send a POST request without creating a new point in the navigation history." It would appear that I provided the solution so that if anyone would come to this question, they may also get solution/roundabout way to this problem. Perhaps you didn't know that this facilitates other stack overflow users. I did answer your question as well as provided roundabout, so I don't think I deserve downvote